# android studio R.string was be reorder

Tags: android-studio

I defined some strings like this:

```
<string name="sun">S</string>
<string name="mon">M</string>
<string name="tue">T</string>
<string name="wed">W</string>
<string name="thu">T</string>
<string name="fri">F</string>
<string name="sat">S</string>
```

In eclipse I can display a day by

```
getString(R.string.sun + dayOfWeek)
```

But in android studio this is not working because `R.string` is changing the order alphabetically. So `R.string.sun + 1` is not `R.string.mon`.

Who can help me configuring android studio so it doesn't reorder with general R class?

Answer (score 1):

From the [R file documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html):

> Although the R class is where resource IDs are specified, you should never need to look there to discover a resource ID.

You're basically trying to use the id numbers, adding one to a id to get the next "logical". But `aapt` can generate them in any order, so never, ever use Ids as numbers: you can't rely on them.

To solve your problem define an [array in XML](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray) using the names of the days from strings resources

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<array name="icons">
    <item>@string/monday</item>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
 </array>
</resources>
```